# Using gcc with MinGW

Tags: gcc, mingw

So, I installed the MinGW base tools according to the instructions given and everything went fine.

Now, when I try to call `gcc` from the Command Prompt, still nothing happens. How do I use gcc?

Answer (score 3):

Add the install path to your `%PATH%` [environment variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable).

to do this, you could do: `SET PATH = %PATH%;C:\MinGw\bin\` when you start the command prompt.

You could set up a shell script that does this

Or you can add it to the [windows environment variables which is more permanent](http://www.google.com/search?q=Add+environment+variables+to+windows&btnG=Search).