# Can we use MinGW to compile a Perl script?

Tags: perl, mingw

I have some problems to compile or run a Perl script in Windows. I have installed MinGW in my Windows to compile C code using the [GCC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Compiler_Collection) package. Now, can I use MinGW to compile Perl script/code and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActivePerl creates shortcuts for .pl files (if you check the box during installation). You can see the association by running the following from a prompt:

```
>assoc .pl
.pl=Perl

>ftype Perl
Perl="C:\Progs\perl5121-ap1201\bin\perl.exe" "%1" %*
```

(Use wahtever `assoc` returned as the argument for `ftype`.)

You can do it yourself with:

```
assoc .pl=Perl
ftype Perl=Perl="C:\Progs\perl5121-ap1201\bin\perl.exe" "%1" %*
```

(Use the correct path for your machine.)

Keep in mind that many scripts require command line inputs, and that the console closes down as soon as the script exits when you launch it from double-clicking. As such, it's often better to run your script from the prompt.

If you have the association setup as above, you can run a Perl script from the console simply by typing its name

```
>script.pl
Hello, World!
```

Or you can be explicit and specify that it requires Perl.

```
>perl script.pl
Hello, World!
```

That assumes that Perl is in the `PATH`. If not, you can specify the whole path to Perl.

```
>C:\Progs\perl5121-ap1201\bin\perl script.pl
Hello, World!
```

Comment: thanks for helping. That's mean I need install ActivePerl first to use perl PATH right?

Comment: @Mohd Isa. No, the PATH is an environment variable. It's configured somewhere in the properties of "My Computer".

Answer (score 4):

No. [GCC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Compiler_Collection) does not include Perl. Try [Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com/) or [ActivePerl for Windows](http://www.activestate.com/activeperl/) which are Perl distributions for Windows.

Comment: @Alan: Before this I has install ActivePerl for my Windows, but I don't know how to use it. I just click file.pl, but nothing happened. So how to compile, run and show the result?

Comment: _[Mohd Isa](http://stackoverflow.com/users/711747/mohd-isa)_: You can run the script by running the command: `perl path\to\file.pl`.

Comment: @Alan oic, need run in cmd to rite?

Comment: @Alan: So what command line I need use to compile and run it?

Comment: _[Mohd Isa](http://stackoverflow.com/users/711747/mohd-isa)_: You do not have to. You could run it with the above command. However, please read: `perldoc -q "How can I compile my Perl program into byte code or C?"`

Answer (score 3):

See PAR::Packer's frontend pp, or "Cava Packager", or IndigoStar's Perl2Exe, or ActiveState's PerlApp