# How can I compile C using cmd.exe in Windows 7 x64

Tags: c, windows, ide, cmd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to compile C programming in Windows 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5691795/how-to-compile-c-programming-in-windows-7)

So I've been playing around with Python and Ruby.
I can run .py and .rb from cmd.exe.
In the near future I'll probably do a clean install on Win 7 and partition my drive to dual boot with Ubuntu.
Anyways, I tried to do the same thing with C but I can't figure it out.
I'm not interested in coding with an IDE like Turbo C.
Can anyone point me in the right direction?
Thank You in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

Command Line C/C++ Compiling

[Walkthrough: Compiling a Native C++ Program on the Command Line (C++)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235639%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). You need to install [Visual Studio Express 2012 products](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/visual-studio-express-products)

[Compile with MinGW GCC](http://www.mingw.org/)

[Compile with Cygwin GCC](http://cygwin.com/packages/gcc-g++/)

C/C++ Interpreter

[CLANG](http://clang.llvm.org/get_started.html)

Comment: If you're serious about learning C, I would recommend avoiding MSVC. It only supports a very old standard of C, and even that only partially (GCC and CLang support both old *and* new). An advantage is builtin support in Visual Studio, if you want to use an IDE --- but there are plenty of alternatives (and for what it's worth, I personally *hate* VS, for various reasons).

Answer (score 0):

I have impression that you don't wont compiler, you wont to execute c scripts, look here :

http://bellard.org/tcc/

With tcc you can run c scripts from command line.