# New MinGW gcc doesn't do anything

Tags: c++, c, mingw

I'm trying to compile a simple `helloworld` program with `MinGW` on Windows and nothing happens. No output, no executable, nothing. I've just installed the latest MinGW with their `mingw-get-inst-20120421.exe` installer. When I use an older version of MinGW that came with `Code::Blocks`, I am able to compile the program. I'm out of ideas and my googling has been in vain. C:\MinGW\bin is on my path and I'm using MSYS.

Command line parameters in MSYS:

```
gcc helloworld.c -o helloworld
```

Comment: Please provide the command line parameters and results. It sounds like you're trying to compile in cmd prompt instead of the msys console.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2368430/using-gcc-with-mingw

Comment: Not really an answer, but I prefer the nuwen (http://nuwen.net/mingw.html) or TDM (http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/) MinGW distributions because their installers just work (nuwen's install is just an extract from an archive - nice and simple). I'll admit, it's been a long time since I tried the 'official' installer; maybe it has improved since then.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Thanks for the recommendation of nuwen, I'm trying it out now.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. No command in msys does anything, e.g. `ls` `sh` `make` etc. I am using Windows XP 32 bit. I thought I might accidentally have a 64 bit version of msys and re-downloaded it, with the same result. Needless to say the msys console won't even start.

Answer (score 2):

Execute the console from the Start menu, Start->MingW->MinGW Shell or from filesystem:

C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\msys.bat

Execute gcc in this shell.

Otherwise you will have to add the minGW/bin directory to your PATH environment variable.

Comment: I am using MSYS, it has the same results.

Comment: What version windows you running?

Comment: let's check your path in msys, execute: `echo $PATH`. Also check the bin directory for gcc. Make sure the installer deployed all your files.

Answer (score -1):

Go to the directory where you have you gcc executable. In my case it's:

```
C:\MingW\bin
```

From there execute gcc:

```
gcc myFile.c
```

If it compiles, than something must screwed up your `$PATH`